# How to get an mySQL field echo a statment if this the value else if this is the other value in PHP

Tags: php, sql

```
$query = "SELECT unitstat FROM tblunits where unitid='VDMRB1001'" ;
$result=mysql_query($query);

//unitstat is the field i'm trying to call
$field=("unitstat");      //is this correct??

while($unitstat = mysql_fetch_field($result))   //is this correct??
  if ($unitstat=="SOLD")
    echo "THIS UNIT IS SOLD!"; 
  else
    echo "THIS UNIT IS FOR SALE!";
```

Comment: Hi Dan, when you have a good answer you should mark it as correct to help future users.

Comment: Look for "Accepting answer" in [faq#howtoask]. You must be logged as the same user who has asked the question - I see that you have created another account. Have you forgot the password?

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_field` returns an object containing field information. For get the sql query result, you should use something like `mysql_fetch_row` or `mysql_fetch_assoc`.

The best thing is to check the [**php manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$query = "SELECT unitstat FROM tblunits where unitid='VDMRB1001'" ;
$result=mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  $unitstat = $row['unitstat'];
  if ($unitstat=="SOLD")
    echo "THIS UNIT IS SOLD!"; 
  else
    echo "THIS UNIT IS FOR SALE!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT unitstat FROM tblunits where unitid='VDMRB1001'" ;
$result=mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo 'THIS UNIT IS ' . ($row['unitstat'] == 'SOLD') ? 'SOLD!' : 'FOR SALE!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query  = "SELECT unitstat FROM tblunits where unitid='VDMRB1001'";           
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while(list($unitstat) = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if ($unitstat == "SOLD")
    echo "THIS UNIT IS SOLD!"; 
else
    echo "THIS UNIT IS FOR SALE!";
}
```